# How to connect to LDAP from Powershell in another server

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I have to query my Active Directory from another windows server using PowerShell through LDAP. I got LDAP connection details, port number, login credential. However, after googling for hours I couldnt find a soultion to connect PowerShell to LDAP. I tried below cmdlet but all returned the error "the term ** is not recognised as the the name of a cmdlet".

```
    New-AdfsLdapServerConnection
    Test-LDAPConnection
```

Can someone please help. I want to connect to my LDAP and run a simple command like

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "Sec-abc-xyz-123-U"'
```

later I want to write my full Powershell script and then use Task scheduler to automate my powershell script. Can someone please let me know how I could connect to LDAP?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thank you for the info. Can you please let me how we use LDAP in PowerShell to connect?

Comment: `Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like "Sec-abc-xyz-123-U"'` is using LDAP already assuming you're running this on a Domain Joined computer. You need to provide more details on what you want to achieve and what issue are you facing if any.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon above command works only within AD server. I am trying to get AD data outside server. I do not know how to enter server details.

Comment: You'll need to install RSAT to use the AD PS Module. If you are not allowed to, then you'll need to learn how to use `adsi` and `adsisearcher`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank you. I installed RSAT and it worked. You are AWESOME :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Santiago Squarzon suggested, you need to install RSAT to use the AD PS Module